# Process multiple 'lines' in apache-spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am very new to Spark and I have a question.

I try to do a simple sentiment analysis with some data.
In the data-file every line contains a product-review.

Here is my code for processing one line:

```
// wordlist
val pos_file = "/user/cloudera/Data/pos_list.txt"
val neg_file = "/user/cloudera/Data/neg_list.txt"

val pos_words = sc.textFile(pos_file).cache().collect().toSet
val neg_words = sc.textFile(neg_file).cache().collect().toSet


val test_string = "Line with positive or negative review."
val test_rdd = sc.parallelize(List(test_string))

val test_rdd2 = test_rdd.flatMap(line => "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn line map (_.toLowerCase) )

val pos = test_rdd2.filter(x => pos_words contains x)
val neg = test_rdd2.filter(x => neg_words contains x)
```

My question is now how to process each record in the rdd (in this case 3):

```
val file_in = "/user/cloudera/Data/teststring.txt"
val data = sc.textFile(file_in).cache()
val reviews = data.flatMap(_.split("\n"))

scala> reviews.count()
res29: Long = 3
```

The following code

```
val reviews2 = reviews.flatMap(line => "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn line map (_.toLowerCase))
```

gives me all words.
I want to get the values for pos and neg for each line/review.
The computation is quite simple: if a word is in a set of pos_words/neg_words then put it in pos/neg. Actually I just count the occurence of postive or negative words.

How do I get something like ('line', 'posvalue', 'negvalue') ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: that line in review2 will give you all words in a line, not a cummulated pos/neg value. Not sure how your scores are supposed to be computed. Could you update your example?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

If i load a textfile, each line in the textfile is a review. I want to get the values for pos and neg for each line/review.
The computation is quite simple: if a word is in a set of pos_words/neg_words then put it in pos/neg. Actually I just count the occurence of postive or negative words.
My problem is that reviews2 holds the words of all reviews so I can't count the words of a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to summarize the question: we want to count the occurrences of certain words (positive, negative) on each line of an input file after it's  'normalized': all alphabetic characters and spaces in lowercase.

Let's assume I've already the two sets of positive and negative words:

```
val posWords: Set[String] = ???
val negWords: Set[String] = ???
```

And an input file with 1 record per line:

```
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

We want a result of the form:

```
(text, posCount, negCount)
```

Let's first define a helper function that lets us count of matches of the words in a sequence of String against a Set of strings:

```
def matches(text:Seq[String], words:Set[String]):Int =
text.map(w => if (words.contains(w)) 1 else 0).sum
```

And finally, we transform each line into the count of both positive and negative matches.

```
val posNegData  = data.map{line => 
    val cleanLine = line.toLowerCase.split("\\W")
    (line, matches(cleanLine, posWords), matches(cleanLine, negWords))
}
```

Here we assume that the expected result is the original string with the positive and negative matches. (This is not clear from the original question)